# Concat / Inner Join MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

im trying to create an sql query with a concat and inner join.
Without the inner join everything works fine, using the inner join i get:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'kk.kundennummer' in 'field list'

This is my query:

```
select 
    kk.kundennummer as customer_id,
    kk.nummer as customer_nr,
    substr(`name`, 1, (length(`name`) - length(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX((`name`), ' ', -1))-1)
        ) as first_name,
    substring_index(`name`,' ',-1) AS last_name,
    k.name1 as company_name,
    kk.Abteilung as department,
    concat(`kk.kundennummer`,`kk.Nummer`) as customer_key, 
    kk.Telefon as phone,
    kk.Telefax as fax,
    kk.Handy as mobile,
    kk.E_Mail as email,
    kk.Geburtstag as birthday,
    kk.Autotelefon as mobile2
from kundenkontakt kk 
    inner join kunden k on (k.Kundennummer = kk.Kundennummer) 
where kk.E_Mail != "";
```

What im doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: are you on a case sensitive System where a capital `K` is not the same like a lower case `k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code (and any similar ones I might have missed):

```
concat(`kk.kundennummer`,`kk.Nummer`) as customer_key,
```

You have no column called "kk.kundennummber" (with the "kk." as part of the column name).  Just remove the backticks:

```
concat(kk.kundennummer, kk.Nummer) as customer_key,
```

Hmm, this is a good reason *not* to use backticks when writing code.  I think they just clutter up queries (unless absolutely necessary), but they can also lead to unexpected errors.

Comment: Thank you! I searched a long.